# Virtual network interface in Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, router, interface, ip-routing

i am trying to setup a VPN server tunnel on my windows PC so that i can connect to  it using remote client VPN hence  routing traffic through that tunnel
client = android

Answer (score 0):

From your Windows box open ncpa.cpl

Press ALT to enable the advanced menu

Select File -> New incoming connection

Create new vpn user (add someone setting)

Check or not how to connect people (from internet or not)

Choose IPv4 and File & Printer Sharing services and click on Allow Access

On Android device install your favorite vpn client (i.e. OpenVpnConnect) and put parameters you configured.

The above instructions are not tested but could be guidelines.

HTH